# SSRS. Specify IF, in expression, to choose month correctly

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-expression

I have expression on Text Box that after StartDate selected It type some text. It working normally, except 1 month of the years is selected It throws an error. I need to specify something like that `IF month = 1 then years = -1 month = 12`. For now my expression looks like:

```
= MonthName(Right(Parameters!StartDate.Value-1,2).ToString()) + " - " + Left((Parameters!StartDate.Value - 100).ToString(),4)
```

And `StartDate` parameter is in format like: `201401, 201402, 201403, 201404, etc`
I can't get correct syntax for It.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
**=Monthname(Dateadd(DateInterval.Month,-2, cdate(Left(Parameters!StartDate.Value,4)&"-"&right(Parameters!StartDate.Value,2)&"-01")).Month,False)**

Comment: Thank you for an answer, but I dont need to specify IFF or Switch? It should make -1 for every month, but If It Is 1 month (January) Ir should convert to something like that:  `years = -1 and month = 12` For example if StartDate is `201401` It should be converted to `201312` and If StarDate is `201405` It should be converted to (as for now Is) `201404`

Comment: Your previous method worked as well! This one `= MonthName(Right(Parameters!StartDate.Value,2),False).ToString()....` And how about to make the same with `MonthName(Right(Parameters!StartDate.Value-2,2).ToString()` ? Here the same problem If I choose 2 month of years (February) for example `201402`

Comment: Instead of doing Parameters!StartDate.Value-2, first convert your date value in proper date format and then use date methods to get the desired output.

Comment: Your last update returning only month, without years.

Comment: give me some details about your requirement.